# Writing a huge file in most efficient way

Tags: php

I am trying to write a file in php that is in the range of 50+ MB.

This is kind of working as expected, though it goes rather slow.

it is running quite simple:

```
$fileAccess = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fileAccess, $line);
*a lot of lines and loops...*
fclose($fileAccess);
```

My question is. Can I do anything to optimize it. 
I send around 350000 `fwrite` statements of around 100-10000 characters to the file, and I was wondering if there is something I can do to make the file generation more efficient.
Is it better to do all these small writes, or should I internally "cache" a bit of the content before writing it, or is there a third option I just don't know about.

I have to keep my memory consumption down, or I will hit server limitation.

Thanks

Comment: `a lot of lines and loops` doesn't tell me anything. You can write 35000 lines there, which will be reasonably quick. You could also loop through 35000 arrays, which will be absolutely wrecking. Also, obligatory JoelOnSoftware: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the overhead of many file writes, you can use just one, for example, I use an array which I implode by new lines at the end to write with;

```
<?php

$filecontent = array();
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");

while ($x == $y)
{
    if ($condition_met)
    {
        $filecontent[] = "Some message to say this worked";
    }
    if ($condition_met)
    {
        $filecontent[] = "Some message to say this failed";
    }
}

$filecontent = implode("\r\n", $filecontent);
fwrite($handle, $filecontent);
fclose($file);
```

It means you have the resource open for the handle, as well as an array of values to be added, simply implode and write once usually works for me

**EDIT**

If you are getting memory overuse, still using an array, you can loop this at the end to avoid having to keep write the write all the time, but you'll still see the same performance hit, I have attempted to reduce this by adding a counter so writes are not done as often;

```
$filecontent = array();
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");

while ($x == $y)
{
    if ($condition_met)
    {
        $filecontent[] = "Some message to say this worked";
    }
}
$counts = 0;
$addtofile = "";
foreach ($filecontent as $addline)
{
    if ($counts < 2500)
    {
        $addtofile .= $addline . "\r\n";
        $counts++;
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite($handle, $addtofile);
        $addtofile = "";
        $counts = 0;
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: That is very similar to what I did before. The problem were it costed to much memory. Therefore I switched to writing single lines, but that seems to have a huge overhead on the serversite, writing that many lines.

Comment: I'll add a second method - hang fire

Comment: @DennisC - added edit and one with a hopeful performance increase by limiting the single writes to 2500 lines (which you can obviously change)

Comment: Used a variation of yours (because of some recursive loops) 
Time spend on server dropped with 90%

Comment: Excellent news - this was untested mostly (in the edit) so I'm glad it's working for you! Here's to hoping you can drop another 90% of the time off :P

Comment: 10 minutes to around 1 minute, is a decent increase :) and yes. could probably optimize it further. (Always seems to be another layer of optimization to do on any code)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
// Copy big file from somewhere else
$src_filepath = 'http://example.com/all_the_things.txt'; $src = fopen($src_filepath, 'r');
$tmp_filepath = '...'; $tmp = fopen($tmp_filepath, 'w');
$buffer_size = 1024;

while (!feof($src)) {                       
   $buffer = fread($src, $buffer_size);     // Read big file/data source/etc. in small chunks
   fwrite($tmp, $buffer);                   // Write in small chunks
}

fclose($tmp_filepath);                      // Clean up
fclose($src_filepath);

rename($tmp_filepath, '/final/path/to/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_put_contents`. Writing to file is slowest part here, so use it as little as possible:

```
$content = '';
$threshold = 1000;
$handler = fopen('my_file.txt', 'a');

foreach ($contents as $i => $data) {
    $content .= $data;

    // Write in batches
    if ($i > $threshold) {
        fwrite($handler, $content);
        $content = ''; // Reset content
    }
}

// Write what's left in $content
if (!empty($content)) {
    fwrite($handler, $content);
}

fclose($handler);
```

Comment: Interested if the overhead of `file_put_contents()` (i.e. open file, write, close file) is better than just writing chunks to a `fopen()` file.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm also interested to see how making many smaller calls to file put or fwrite compares to just one with a larger, concatenated string

Comment: wouldn't it be better with one fopen and fclose, and then use what you describe. Combining a set amount of lines before pushing it to the file.